# Why does Observable.subscribe() throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: rx-java2

As I was wondering what would happen if I threw some exception in the subscribe method of Observable.. for instance:

```
Observable<SomeClass> observable = Observable.create(emitter -> {
        throw new SomeException();
    });
    observable.subscribe(observer);
```

I came across this code in the rxjava library:

```
@SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.NONE)
@Override
public final void subscribe(Observer<? super T> observer) {
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(observer, "observer is null");
    try {
        observer = RxJavaPlugins.onSubscribe(this, observer);

        ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(observer, "The RxJavaPlugins.onSubscribe hook returned a null Observer. Please change the handler provided to RxJavaPlugins.setOnObservableSubscribe for invalid null returns. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Plugins");

        subscribeActual(observer);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) { // NOPMD
        throw e;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Exceptions.throwIfFatal(e);
        // can't call onError because no way to know if a Disposable has been set or not
        // can't call onSubscribe because the call might have set a Subscription already
        RxJavaPlugins.onError(e);

        NullPointerException npe = new NullPointerException("Actually not, but can't throw other exceptions due to RS");
        npe.initCause(e);
        throw npe;
    }
}
```

notice this code in particular:

```
 NullPointerException npe = new NullPointerException("Actually not, but can't throw other exceptions due to RS");
        npe.initCause(e);
        throw npe;
```

So my exception is wrapped inside a NullPointerException, instead of being thrown directly. My question is why and what does this mean: "Actually not, but can't throw other exceptions due to RS".. what is RS?

This seems like very dodgy code to me and nothing is mentioned about it in the [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/ObservableOnSubscribe.html)

Comment: maybe a good question for @akarnokd